# The server tag is not well formed javascript asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am trying to append to a table inside a javascript function:

```
function fillTable(item) {
        document.getElementById("mybody").innerHTML += "<tr><td id=\"td1\" runat=\"server\">" + item.Tasks[0].Value.timeStamp + "</td></tr>";
    }
```

but I get the error "The server tag is not well formed"

Comment: You need to understand the difference between server-side code and client-side code.

Comment: My mistake, I'll remove that tag. You are right SLaks, now that I think about it I don't need the runat=server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASPX is trying to parse the string literal inside your Javascript as a server-side control.

You can use string concatenation to make it not look like a server-side control:

```
"<tr><" + "td run" + "at=...
```

However, you shouldn't be doing this in the first place; `runat="server"` is meaningless in client-side code.

Comment: The first half of the answer didn't fix the issue, but the second part of the answer is correct, runat=server is not needed.